# Creating a pie chart illustrating a column of values in Numbers or Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a checklist of songs, where one column represents each song's tempo. I'd like to create a pie chart that shows the total number of slow songs, medium-tempo songs and up-tempo songs. Creating a chart of numerical values is simple. But I don't see any logical way to bend a chart to my will, when I've got a list that reads something like this:

```
TITLE    TEMPO
Song 1 - med
Song 2 - up
Song 3 - up
Song 4 - slow
Song 5 - med
Song 6 - slow
```

I just want to see a pie chart that represents the total number of songs as 100%, and the percentages of slow, medium, and up-tempo songs as slices.

I'm stumped. I suppose I could come up with some kind of if/then/else formula that would put the values in a hidden cell, but that seems terribly inefficient. Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks!

Brad

Answer (score 4):

Pie charts don't do any aggregation for you. You feed the pie chart the value you want it to show.

Any aggregation will need to be done in the worksheet. There are several approaches for this

- use a pivot chart - Select the data table, Insert > pivot chart. Change chart type to pie chart. Drag "Tempo" into Axes and again into Values

[image]

- aggregate with formulas, then create a chart. Put the three tempi into three cells, then use formulas to count how many times the tempo appears in the list. Create a chart of the results. The formula in cell E2 is `=COUNTIF(B:B,D2)` copied down.

[image]

With either technique, once the chart is in place, you can add Data Labels and format them to show "percentage".

Please note that pie charts are fine for two or three data values, but if you have more slices, you will be better off with a horizontal bar chart. It will be much easier to read.